# Tools for print type of variables in C program

Tags: c, static-analysis

I am looking for a tool that can output the type of variables in C program in text format. Could you please suggest tools that can perform this task?

Comment: What type of variables are you talking about? External / global / argument / local variables? What would be the purpose?

Comment: I expect to cover all kinds of variables. I will use this information to make further analyses of the C program. For example, in the statement `*(a->b) = x;`, I want to find the address that is referred: `address = a + offsetof(struct typeOfA, b)`.